# perl glob matching files on windows vs linux

Tags: perl, cgi, glob

I have the following code in a cgi script that just bundles up xml files into a zip for downloading:

```
my $obj = Archive::Zip->new();
foreach my $xml_file (glob(File::Spec->catfile($in_path,"*.xml")))
{
    $obj->addFile($xml_file);
}
$obj->writeToFileNamed($zipfile_name);
```

This works fine on unit tests and when I run it on Linux, but when installed on windows, I get:

```
Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 249.
```

In both cases, it works fine on Linux and under unit test, but fails when installed on windows (there are xml files in the directory that should be picked up...).

Comment: Is there a space in the Windows path?

Comment: @ikegami,  You are right.  I changed two things at once when I ran that test.  The if defined does not make a difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think choroba's comment is correct.  Since it only happens when you install on windows rather than when you test on windows, I'll bet that it is a "C:\Program Files" space issue.  It is listed in the docs for perl's File::Glob:

> Due to historical reasons, CORE::glob() will also split its
>   argument on whitespace, treating it as multiple patterns, whereas
>   bsd_glob() considers them as one pattern.

This could easily break things.  The docs recommend using bsd_glob() instead of glob in this case.

I can cut and paste your code and run it on windows with $in_path == ".", but it breaks when I use $in_path = "C:\Path With Spaces". Also, with spaces, I am pretty sure it will fail on linux as well.